# why spring-boot-starter-tomcat is not optional in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-starter

According by https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html and the pom of spring-boot-starter-web: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.4/jar.
We could replace tomcat by jetty in spring-boot. So why not mark it optional in pom?

Answer (score 1):

If `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` was marked as optional, no embedded container would be provided by default and an app using `spring-boot-starter-web` would fail to start. Using Tomcat by default is a trade-off between convenience for the majority of users who are happy to use Tomcat and making things every so slightly more complicated for those that want to use Jetty or Undertow.